# How To Create A Relational Contents in Orchard Core

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to create a content in orchard core with 1 to n relation? For example create a content which register a person with several addresses!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it should be solved with bag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Í solved it with bag. I created bag for each entity that needed to be a list